# Are the following polynomials convex (or concave) on the interval $[0,1]^3$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

I am trying to figure out if the following polynomials are convex or concave on the region $[0, 1]^3$ for every variable, but I wasn't sure how to go about it for a region rather than the entire function. I plotted them for various values of $x,y,z$ and they *appeared* concave, but nothing is true until proven.

I have other functions similar to these two, so if you could explain the method that would be very appreciated! 
$$
f(x,y,z) = 1+y+2z-2yz+xyz
$$
$$
g(x,y,z) = 1+2x+2y-z-2xy-yz+xyz
$$

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave the definitions of "convex" and "concave" that you are working with, and perhaps indicated what about those definitions is confusing to you.  I am also not sure that I understand what you mean by the interval $[0,1]$, as your functions are functions of three variables (i.e. they are functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$), and an interval is parameterized by a single variable.

Comment: The domain is $[0,1]^3$ which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson sorry I meant that each variable $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ so convex in the region $[0,1]^3$. Made the correction

Comment: Maybe you can show that the hessian is positive or negative semidefinite on the given region using the positivstellensatz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function is indefinite. For $z=1$ the Hessian over $(x,y)$ is $0.5 \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and has eigenvalues 0.5 and -0.5. The eigenvalues indicate directions of convexity and concavity. For example, an eigenvector corresponding to -0.5 is $(1,-1)$, so the function is concave on lines $\{(x,y,1) + t (1,-1,0) : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Similarly, the function is convex lines $\{(x,y,1) + t (1,1,0) : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

The second function is also indefinite. For $z=1$ the Hessian over $(x,y)$ is the same as for the first function.

For higher order polynomials you need to check the eigenvalues for all potential values of $(x,y,z)$. If you cannot determine the eigenvalues, you could sample a few values, and if you suspect the function is not indefinite, you may be able to prove that using the positivstellensatz.